# BitVec incorrectly appends 0s instead of 1s

Tags: data-structures, rust, bitvector

I am a beginner at Rust. I am trying to use the [BitVec](https://crates.io/crates/bit-vec) library to represent an array of bits. I started playing with it by appending sequences of 0s or 1s, but I am having some problems at doing so. When I append a sequence of x 0s *then* a sequence of y 1s, what it does instead is to append x+y zeroes. Note that if I just append 1s without appending 0s before, it works. Here is my code:

```
extern crate bit_vec;
use bit_vec::BitVec;

fn main(){
    let mut bits = BitVec::new();   // creates an empty array of bits
    append_zero(&mut bits);
    append_one(&mut bits);
    append_zero(&mut bits);
    append_one(&mut bits);
    append_one(&mut bits);          // everything works perfectly till here
    append_n_ones(&mut bits, 2);    // this works
    append_n_zeroes(&mut bits, 3);  // this too
    append_n_ones(&mut bits, 2);    // this appends 2 zeroes instead!
    println!("{:?}", bits);
}

fn append_zero(vector: &mut BitVec) {
    vector.push(false);
}

fn append_one(vector: &mut BitVec) {
    vector.push(true);
}

fn append_n_zeroes(vector: &mut BitVec, n: usize) {
    let mut to_append = BitVec::from_elem(n, false);  // creates a BitVec with n 0s
    println!("trying to append: {:?}", to_append);
    vector.append(&mut to_append);
}

fn append_n_ones(vector: &mut BitVec, n: usize) {
    let mut to_append = BitVec::from_elem(n, true);  // creates a BitVec with n 1s
    println!("trying to append: {:?}", to_append);
    vector.append(&mut to_append);
}
```

This is the output:

```
trying to append: 11
trying to append: 000
trying to append: 11
010111100000
```

Note that the last line should have been `010111100011`. Moreover, before appending it, `11` is correctly printed. But then it appends `00`.

I am using [this website](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to test my Rust code, but locally it has the same problems. I tried to look at the [code for the BitVec library](https://docs.rs/crate/bit-vec/0.6.2/source/src/lib.rs) but it is too advanced for my level of Rust at the moment.

Comment: [Issue 63: BitVec::append fails silently](https://github.com/contain-rs/bit-vec/issues/63) apparently `append` can silently corrupt the vector.

Comment: @Masklinn thanks! it seems that I will have to do it without this lib, as they commented on making a PR to fix the error but it doesn't seem that anybody commited anything yet.

Comment: There are actually two PRs, but the crate doesn't seem to be much maintained. Also interestingly using `extend` works fine, possibly because it skipped some of the optimisations. I got the idea because when looking for the documentation I checked the wrong crate (`bitvec` whose author commented here) and there `append` just calls `extend`. You can imagine my confusion when that cleared away the issue despite there being no reason to given the code I was looking at.

Comment: @Masklinn can you write this as an answer? I would accept it. If you can explain how I can use `extend`, I am trying but it asks me for an iterator.

Comment: ah ok, I just have to use `.iter()` on my BitVec object (`to_append`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bit_vec` crate, while old and popular, is in maintenance-only. I am the author of a replacement, [`bitvec`](https://crates.io/crates/bitvec), which behaves as you desire and (in my opinion) is a better product.

You can use your code as-written by replacing `bit_vec` with `bitvec` and `BitVec::from_elem` with `BitVec::<Lsb0, usize>::repeat`. Unfortunately, `bitvec` is not available on the Rust playground, so I can't show you directly.